# Create Loader for my website

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, turbolinks

I am trying to create loader for my website but it is not working .I am using turbolinks classic for this operation.The loader loads after the page load which i don't want .I need when page is loading that time i need my loader to load and when the page gets load the loader should get disappear both things are not working.Here is my code

```
 <div id="content-wrapper">
        <div class="loader"><img src='/assets/gionee-loader.gif' style='width:100px;height:100px;margin-left:30%;margin-top:10%;display:block;'/></div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div class="main-box clearfix">
                    <div class="clearfix">
                       <div class="common_page gsb1">
                           <div class="hdr">
                               <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-3">
                                      <h4>Dashboard</h4>
                                    </div>
                                <div class="col-md-5">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-4 pull-right">
                                    <%=render 'common/date'%>
                                </div>                
                            </div>    
                        </div> 
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
          <center>
<div class="table-responsive custom-bg">
<table class="custom-table" cellspacing="0">

<tr>

<td><table width="100%" border="0" class="tbl-second-lvl" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">

  <tr>
    <td> Name</td>
    <td>Email </td>

    </tr>
<tr></tr>
 <%@dashboard.each do |dashboard|%>
  <tr>
    <td><b><%=dashboard[:NAME]%></b></td>
    <td><%=dashboard[:email]%></td>


  </tr>
  <%end%>





</table></td>  
</tr>

</table>
<%= will_paginate @dashboard %>
</div>
</center>
          <%=render 'common/footer'%>
   </div>

 <script>
    $("#retailer").attr("class","active")



    $(document).on('page:load', function(event) {
      $('.loader img').css("display","none"); 
    });


  </script>
```

But the loader is not loading the image Can anyone tell me how to do that.And I don't want to use ajax for this thing

Comment: this looks like an unloader -because the image is displayed on before unload - perhaps you want to remove the `display:none;` form the image style attribute

Comment: I mean the image is `display:none` until "before-unload" ... in other words, it's never visible,

Comment: Seriously? Look at my first content

Comment: Actually my loader is not working it is loading after the page is load which i don't want. I need when page is loading that time i need loader and after the page gets fully loaded the loader should disappear

Answer (score 0):

set display to block initially :-

```
         <div class="loader"><img src='/assets/gionee-loader.gif' style='width:100px;height:100px;margin-left:30%;margin-top:10%;display:block;'/></div>
```

or just

`<div class="loader"><img src='/assets/gionee-loader.gif' style='width:100px;height:100px;margin-left:30%;margin-top:10%;'/></div>`

and remove

```
$(document).on('page:before-unload', function(event) {
//remove  $('.loader img').css("display","block");
});
```

As a result,the loader image will be not visible after document is loaded fully but is visible till then

Comment: if loader is still not visible , try use timeout while setting display to none inside $(document).on(page:load)

Comment: You cant show loader until the html loads , unless you are using some sort of templating system.

Comment: how to do that   some example or something?

Comment: i use angularjs for frontend.Its great framework with many features

Comment: But loader is supposed to work the way it is working .. without loading html it wont be displayed , even in templates , until the loader templates loads it wont show